# using atom as external diff tool in tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn, atom-editor

I'm trying to use Atom as external diff tool in tortoise svn.

Manually I am able to open files from command line, via palette run 'Pane: Split left and move active item' and then 'Split Diff:Enable'.

Any idea how to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tortoise-svn plugin, it lets you use all the tortoiseSVN commands by clickn rightClick on the project folder inside atom (in the treeview).

If you are lookin for something like changing the color of the file whenever it is different from the repo in the treeview like with github, then you can install the plugin SVN. Apparently that plugin does that, but im stucked in how to make it work.

Comment: thanks, I know about the tortoise-svn plugin. What I want to achieve is the other way around - have tortoise svn open diffs in atom. E.g. when I want to compare changes I made to the base, I right click and pick tortoiseSVN --> diff. Currently I have KDiff3 set up as external diff tool, as I like it more than default tortoise diff viewer.  So I can open 2 files, split panes and run split diff on them as described above - manually.  And the question is can I do it from command line to set it up in tortoise.  Sth like:  atom.exe --pane1 file1 --pane2 --exec 'Split Diff:Enable'

Comment: Oh, i see. the git plugin have something like that, but you see both versions in the same file [git-diff-details](https://atom.io/packages/git-diff-details). But  it doesnt work for svn.
Also, apparently [this](https://atom.io/packages/svn) pakage  does the same as the git-diff but with svn. but i couldn make it work, maybe you have more luck then me. =D